# Jenkins pipeline retry option triggers two builds at a time, one in execution state other in pending state for a single click

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

For example
I have clicked on retry option at build number 2 in Jenkins pipeline view, where as build number 3 gets start and build number 4 also gets start and awaits at pending state.

Why the build number 4 is getting started parallelly and how to avoid this one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried unticking the "allow concurrent builds" option?

Comment: I could not find this option anywhere in jenkins pipeline configure section. Could you please guide me where I need to check

Comment: It's usually within the job config. Above the "build triggers " section or something. Or you can add it inside the pipeline by doing options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
    }

Answer (score 0):

@shree, I have also seen this scenario in localhost, later I have found that there is an issue with the google chrome browser, somehow it is not compatible with that, please try it with another Firefox browser and check.